# app engine standard environment call bigquery python

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I am trying to deploy a simple standard app engine in python and from there to make bigquery queries through python bigquery client.

The code is as simple as these:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import webapp2
import os
from google.cloud import bigquery

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):


  client = bigquery.Client(project = "ancient-ceiling-125223")
  project_name = str(client.project)

  query_job = client.query("select 1")

  assert query_job.state == 'RUNNING'

  iterator = query_job.result(timeout= 30)

  rows = list(iterator)

  self.response.write('nothing to see %s' % (project_name))


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
[('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

The error log: The error appears in the dummy query request

```
*('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(209 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(209 bytes read)) (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py:1528)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ancient-ceiling-125223/20171115t104156.405543624689752939/main.py", line 35, in get
    query_job = client.query("select 1")
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ancient-ceiling-125223/20171115t104156.405543624689752939/lib/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 986, in query
    job._begin(retry=retry)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ancient-ceiling-125223/20171115t104156.405543624689752939/lib/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py", line 397, in _begin
    method='POST', path=path, data=self._build_resource())
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ancient-ceiling-125223/20171115t104156.405543624689752939/lib/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 271, in _call_api
    return call()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ancient-ceiling-125223/20171115t104156.405543624689752939/lib/google/api_core/retry.py", line 260, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ancient-ceiling-125223/20171115t104156.405543624689752939/lib/google/api_core/retry.py", line 177, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ancient-ceiling-125223/20171115t104156.405543624689752939/lib/google/cloud/_http.py", line 290, in api_request
    headers=headers, target_object=_target_object)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ancient-ceiling-125223/20171115t104156.405543624689752939/lib/google/cloud/_http.py", line 183, in _make_request
    return self._do_request(method, url, headers, data, target_object)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ancient-ceiling-125223/20171115t104156.405543624689752939/lib/google/cloud/_http.py", line 212, in _do_request
    url=url, method=method, headers=headers, data=data)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ancient-ceiling-125223/20171115t104156.405543624689752939/lib/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 186, in request
    method, url, data=data, headers=request_headers, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ancient-ceiling-125223/20171115t104156.405543624689752939/lib/requests/sessions.py", line 502, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ancient-ceiling-125223/20171115t104156.405543624689752939/lib/requests/sessions.py", line 652, in send
    r.content
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ancient-ceiling-125223/20171115t104156.405543624689752939/lib/requests/models.py", line 825, in content
    self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or bytes()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ancient-ceiling-125223/20171115t104156.405543624689752939/lib/requests/models.py", line 750, in generate
    raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(209 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(209 bytes read))*
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like an authentication problem. Just for testing, does it work if you try a very simple query such as `"select 1"`? Also, I suppose you are running on flex environment is that correct?

Comment: A simple query won't work neither. I am running in standard environment.

Comment: The code you show doesn't match the traceback, which shows a `for row in query_job:` statement - the problem may be obscured by that omission. If you have a simpler example post the traceback matching it.

Comment: I'm wondering if an object is going out of scope (in the omitted code) and causing the connection to be closed prematurely.

Comment: A more simpliefied code I just deployed for testing: client = bigquery.Client(project = "ancient-ceiling-125223")
     project_name = str(client.project)
   
    query_job = client.query("select 1")
    
    assert query_job.state == 'RUNNING'
    
    iterator = query_job.result(timeout= 30)
    
    rows = list(iterator)

Comment: Please update your question instead of writing code in comments.

Comment: sorry, just updated the question

Comment: Can we use the BigQuery Python client library in standard app engine environment, or should we configure a flex environment?

Comment: Just an update, I tried another way, basicly using googleapiclient library and oauth2client library, and create a bigquery api based on that, and it works perfectly.

Comment: @CharlesZhan  You may want to add a answer with your solution.

Answer (score 5):

I could not make it work using python bigquery client library, Here is what I found working in standard app engine environment,

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import webapp2

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):

    credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
    service = build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)

    datasets = service.datasets().list(projectId="ancient-ceiling-125223").execute()

    self.response.write('datasets: %s' % datasets)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
    [('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

Comment: way to go! that's why I asked you about the environment, I also couldn't make the google-cloud API work for Standard, only the googleapiclient as well. What I recommend though is to create your service outside of the request (in this [repo](https://github.com/WillianFuks/example_dataproc_twitter/tree/master/gae/exporter) there's an example of how I do that). Notice as well that if your query takes longer then 60s then this approach won't work. You might have to schedule your queries then.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The repo is really helpful

Comment: I can confirm that the BigQuery client API still does not work with App Engine standard environment. This incomplete and confusing blog post (https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/how-to-build-a-bi-dashboard-using-google-data-studio-and-bigquery) shows a way to query BigQuery tables using the service discovery API, though it does not explicitly say that is what it is doing. It seems like a heinous oversight that GAE does not work with standard client APIs...

Comment: we are using service discovery api to make BigQuery calls in app engine all the time. it works pretty robust. Haven't tried standard client api for a while.